# Why the point of a ramp function where its derivative doesn't exist is not taken into account?

Tags: capacitor

In a caltech course on physics by prof. Goldstein it was mentioned that in the apex point of a triangular-shaped (2D pyramid-shaped) function its derivative doesn't exist as there are no points in the vicinity of this point to take approximation from for a tangent. I was curious about how this applies to a triangular-shaped electronic ramp (capacitor) function. I learned tutorials by Neso Academy and others on differentiation of unit ramp and step functions and found out that while differentiating the ramp function through its apex point this discontinuity point where its derivative doesn't exist seems to not be taken into account and it is assumed that a unit ramp function has a continuous derivative. Whereas while differentiating a unit step function,
it is at least mentioned that there are 2 discontinuity points in this function.

I'm a beginner in electrical engineering and my main interest in this question is to track how an electronic ramp function (what is displayed on an oscilloscope from charging and discharging a capacitor, probably) is generated both mathematically and by electronics components. Can it be that these discontinuity points (and possible other math) in electronic functions be sort of irrelevant when applying an overall (intended) function of an electronic component or circuit?

Comment: You can have discontinuities in a theoretical ideal square wave (which is the derivative of triangle wave). Surely the real hardware can't produce ideal square wave, there is always some raise/fall time to it.

Comment: That's true. The point is that if you were to calculate a magnetic field generated by a changing electric field, so in such discontinuity point where a derivative of a function does not exist there should exist no electric field and therefore no magnetic field?

Comment: Such a point *in theory* has a time duration of *zero*, so who cares what the value of something during zero time? (note, that there are some special functions such as [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) which has a duration of zero, but we do care about it very much. But that's only because it has an infinite amplitude. It's another purely mathematical construct to simplify calculations).

Comment: @HelenKJ The FFT, for example, is always continuous. Not discontinuous. If you want to see how it is able to approximate an instantaneous transition between two discrete points then [see here](https://youtu.be/r6sGWTCMz2k?t=1346). Electronics is always continuous. Not discontinuous. So this may help you. Not sure, though.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Such point would have a zero time duration probably in case of a unit ramp function which begins on a negative x-axis and has its apex point on a 0 point of x-axis denoting time. If a ramp function would be shifted anywhere to the left/right on the x-axis, its apex point would occupy an actual point space on an x-axis and the absolute value of this point on an x-axis should probably provide a non-zero time. In theory such a point of absent derivative occupies a space on x and y axes. What applications are Dirac Delta functions used for?

Comment: @jonk Fourier transform employs trigonometric functions (cosine) which have a continuous derivative anywhere by default. I'm not sure how differentiation is applied for the Fourier transformed. It's only the derivative of a ramp function which is discontinuous at 1 point, not the primary function. But I may suppose that electronic components implementing the Fourier transform itself can still operate with discontinuities at the base level.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you describe the triangle wave as a series of line segments (hopefully you saw this in the Caltec course).

Electrically a triangle wave is synthesized by integrating a square wave, possibly by using a switchable current source driving a capacitor.  If you look closely at the output of a typical analog function generator, you'll notice that the points of the triangle waves aren't perfect -- they're either rounded, or they contain spikes, or they have "hiccups", etc.

In a real electronic circuit, you cant get perfect points on the triangle wave.  Circuits can't act infinitely fast, so at some scale the peaks of the triangle wave (even if it has hiccups or spikes) will be continuous and rounded.  We *model* the output of the triangle wave generator as a mathematically perfect triangle wave when we can get away with it, because trying to describe just how it might be rounded, and what's going on in that teeny interval where it is rounded, gets very messy and complicated.  If we can approximate the thing by the mathematical ideal without losing much accuracy in the answer we want, that's what we do.

This is, by the way, what we do in **pretty much all of engineering and science**.  The universe is infinitely complicated.  If you want to know how many equations you need to **exactly** describe the behavior of your signal generator + oscilloscope, count the electrons and then multiply by 2 -- and that leaves out a bunch of very real protons and neutrons, and an infinite number of virtual particles.  So the first step to solving any problem -- often so early that it's not stated -- is to say "how can I simplify this to the point where I can solve it before I die of old age?"

Answer (score 0):

Discontinuities in derivatives imply infinite bandwidth.

We can't create  infinite bandwidth in reality.

> " discontinuity points (and possible other math) in electronic functions be sort of irrelevant "

NO

These continuities are very relevant to high quality signal generators, As they imply the Quality or limitations of synthesizing the signal for calibration.

But for everyday, triangle signals discontinuities are irrelevant, IFF we say the **signal is confined to a 40 dB dynamic range or 9 harmonics of a triangle wave.**

- The closest to impulse or step function in rise time might be the shortest spark between capacitor discharge between needles or ESD with a key to a doorknob (1~10ps) other than special semiconductor methods.
- The **slew rate at the transition is always limited by current or driver resistance and load capacitance.** All TTL, Op Amps and CMOS have controlled output impedance defined by specs for Vol/Iol  at some Iol.
- The ratio of spectral bandwidth  to frequency of repetition rate is never infinite but gives a rough idea on the number of harmonics. 99th harmonic is about -81dB down.
- Since  a Triangle is just the Integral of a square wave, the triangles harmonics are more attenuated by -6dB /octave
- Since a square wave has no even harmonics after integration , the 3rd harmonic goes down from -7 to -19 dB or -12dB more than from the previous one.

**So the "continuities" are represented by how many harmonics exist, the Bandwidth of the signal, as well as your sensitivity of signal above the noise level.**

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they're very useful and a lot to learn.

Comment: As the question sounds a bit "off-the-ground" in less practical context mentioned, there can be many directions of interpretation. For my electronics project (for which I probably should create a separate question, but for now can't bring more details about it) I would only need for now to generate a user-defined set of frequencies (Hz-KHz range). And I would need to know what would be the physical difference in generating them via a PC (python) program and via a function generator.

Comment: New question, but CMOS Schmitt Relaxation OSC. Input signal Buffered with a pot for f adj. is easiest way to keep constant amplitude with variable f.